# Vertical axis of the magnitude Bode plot

Tags: bode-plot

Why is the vertical axis in the magnitude Bode plot linear?

I am confused because i know that if we want to obtain the magnitude Bode plot of the frequency response, we take the decibel value of the magnitude of the frequency response, and since the decibel value is basically equal to multiplying the log value of the magnitude by 20, the vertical axis of the plot should be logarithmic. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I don't know which Bode plot you are looking at, but the ones I usually see the vertical axis is in dB units, which are logarithmic. Sure, the dB values are spaced linearily.

Comment: Why are they spaced linearily?

Comment: Because linear spacing of `log x` values translates into exponential spacing in `x`.

Comment: The horiz has to be log too!  derivative of the slope is then +/- 1n per decade and 20dB per n orders or 6dB per octave

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you're effectively suggesting a double-application of `log`. Decibels already represent logarithmic voltage. If you were to show decibels on a logarithmic axis, the vertical scale would be *logarithmic* logarithmic voltage which is not useful for analysis.

Comment: If i plot a set of points on a log-scale, doest it meant that i take the logarithm of these points ?

Comment: Yes, it does mean you would have taken the logarithm of those points.

Comment: Thanks alot Mr.Reinderien

Answer (score 1):

Voltage ratios as real numbers and their equivalent in decibels: -

- 0.001 ≡ -60 dB
- 0.010 ≡ -40 dB
- 0.100 ≡ -20 dB
- 1.000 ≡    0 dB
- 10.00 ≡ +20 dB
- 100.0 ≡ +40 dB
- 1000  ≡ +60 dB

Do you see that the real numbers require a log scale and that decibels need a linear scale to represent the same quantity?

Comment: Thanks mr.Andy you helped me.

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey do you know what to consider doing next?

Comment: Yes my mistake was very silly, thanks again for clarification

Comment: @AhmadEldesokey no, I don't expect you to condemn yourself and pull hair out. I'm asking, for the working of this site, you know what to do next?

Comment: I had thought that the function f(x)=log(x) produces produces outputs that are not linearly spaced.

Comment: No i do not know Mr.Andy, what should i do ?

Comment: If you don't have any residual questions left you should [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why people give their time freely to help. Then you should consider up-voting answers that are good and selecting the answer that is best for formal acceptance. This is basically the small responsibility that you burden for getting answers. The same applies to your earlier questions.

Comment: Sure, i will do that .